# Integrating Google Maps in OBIEE

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3, obiee

I come to you in the hope of finding a solution to a problem I encountered when I embed Google Maps in OBIEE.
Indeed, after following the standard procedure defined on this link:

http://onlyobi.blogspot.fr/2014/03/obiee-11g-google-map-integration-guest.html

I get the following error appears in OBIEE:

"Google has disabled use of the Google Maps API for this application. The key provided is not a valid Google API key or is not a licensed version 3 API key
Google Maps Javascript on this site. If you are the owner of this applicatio, please go to ... "

Thank you for your support,

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using the maps visualization from Google? More details here:

https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/map

We use this in OBIEE to display certain data on maps.

Answer (score 0):

Using MapViewer, we can integrate google maps with the OBIEE 11g/12c. More details is  here:

```
https://support.oracle.com/epmos/faces/DocumentDisplay?_afrLoop=363666329275914&parent=EXTERNAL_SEARCH&sourceId=HOWTO&id=1485088.1&_afrWindowMode=0&_adf.ctrl-state=rota6my7h_102
```